# Is there any way to implement the logic for getting notified when somw value changes in Database in Asp.Net core without SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mysql-workbench, real-time

I am develping an website where i need real time notifications.As soon as the database value is changed it should be reflected in the website and i don't want to use SignalR because it is not available in MySql.

Please give me the solution or any references

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you're really saying is that MySQL doesn't have a similar feature to SQL Dependency. This has nothing to do with SignalR specifically. The correct way to do real-time updates between a webserver and a client is to use SignalR. How you decide when to send those updates is separate. With SQL Server you could use SQL Dependency. But that doesn't exist with MySQL so you need to write your own backend service to poll the relevant database table for changes and then push a message to SignalR.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes you are right. If you have any related reference to createing custom backend service then please mention here.It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Well, what did you search for already? What do you need to know exactly? Where are you stuck? First, learn how to make a background service with .NET. Then, presumably, learn how to make it query MySQL if you don't know already, then learn how to make it connect to SignalR. I can't really tell you what to do because I have no idea what your level of knowledge is or where specifically you are lacking the understanding. There are plenty of tutorials already you can easily find by searching online.

Comment: I need real time notification in my website using MySql. The website is in asp.net core. I have used entity framework and Identity framework.I just want to need how to create backend service and more functions if required to implement this functionality.

Comment: If you want to know how to create a backend service then find one of Microsoft's tutorials about it.